# keyof Hover bug in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

So when I hover type as it is shown in the picture result is keyof interface, how can I fix this
so I get keys Union as result on hover?
BTW it works just fine but it is very annoying.

[hover state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPtuB.png)

Comment: I think it's just when there's too many keys in the object, it will just show `keyof xyz` and not show the union type. Have you tried if it works with less keys?

Comment: yes, I thought that too but it works only on one key ,but in my friend's editor we tried with the first example and in his editor all 5 keys are visible

Comment: Have you checked the versions of your editors, because with my VS Code it also doesn't display the union type.

Comment: yep, that was the case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like later versions of typescript do not show the resolved union type literals of the keyof operator when hovering over a variable declaration.

I had typescript version 4.6.3 installed globally on my machine. It would not show type infertance resolution on hover.

type PersonProps = keyof Person; // hover on PersonProp shows "keyof Person"

I switched my typescript version to 3.6.2 in my local directory and now I can see

type PersonProps = keyof Person; // hover on PersonProp  now shows "name" | "age" | "hasGf" | "contactInfo"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).